# Power button not working and power light not lighting up after Lenovo Yoga 730 13IKB reassembly

Tags: laptop, power, laptop-repair

I bought a iFixit computer repair kit and opened up my old Lenovo Yoga 730 13IKB. I had intended to replace the battery until I realized that I had bought the wrong battery. But I was still curious, so I started taking apart the rest of the computer, including unscrewing and taking out the power button. When I reassembled the computer with full intent to use it, I noticed that the power button wasn't clicking. When I pushed on it, it didn't come out and it didn't make the click. After a few more tries at reassembly, I was able to get it to a point where I do hear a click but the computer does not turn on. What's more, when I plug in the power cable, the light on the side that indicates charging is no longer lit.

I'm hoping to avoid going to a repair shop if I can, but I would appreciate any pointers. I did find a lot of disassembly videos and tutorials on youtube but I didn't find any good reassembly materials at all, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Reassembly is just the reverse of disassembly. Check every step carefully.

Comment: Look carefully for wires that might have been broken, e.g., pinched in case or repeated flexed at connector.

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Hardware Maintenance Manual](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/yoga730-13ikb_hmm_201810.pdf).